# Using expiring Cookies to allow certain time limted features to users on a web application

Tags: php, session, cookies

I am creating an web application which allows user to post some article/blog on application. I want to allow users to edit the blog only uptil limited time of creating that blog. Like say just 15-20 minutes.

**To provide this feature I am thinking of taking help of cookies. Whenever a new blog is created, I will create an expiring cookie on user's computer. Whenever user tries to edit a blog, that corresponding cookie must be present and sent to the server, if no cookie present/expired then no edit allowed!**

Is this a good way to implement this functionality? Are there any better alternatives to this ?

I do not want to make a read from the database to see what time blog was created and then allow him to edit or not.(My DB is not read optimized, it is write optimized) I know if the cookies are disabled then functionality could not be implemented with that user or if user changed the computer in between, but you can safely assume that I can live with those limitations. Any comments, feedback, criticism welcomed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cookies expirations can be manipulated easily. You would need to store this data on the server side in a session (persisted either with a file, memcache, or your database), or you can use the data attached to the blog post.

Your claim that your database engine is not read optimized is hogwash. If it's not custom written, I assure you it can handle a query to check when a row was created (provided that is stored).

Comment: My blog data already contains the timestamp of when it was created, so is it safe to use that timestamp (with Javascript, I guess ??!) to decide whther or not to show edit button to the user? Is this method safe ?

Comment: Cant user manipulate this data attached to the blog on webapage, in any manner ??

Comment: It sounds like you're lacking familiarity with the elements you're tying together here. Unfortunately it's out of the scope of this question for me to explain the entire request cycle of a PHP script with forays into security and state.

Comment: You can safely use the cookie to control the display of the edit panel, but you should ignore the cookie in your PHP script and instead check the timestamp in the database to control whether the user's edits should be saved. If the user spoofs the cookie, the worst they can do is *try* to edit the blog, but your system will block it.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of database are you using?  MySQL or PostgreSQL would be able to handle this with no problem.

If you store the cookies on the user's computer then they can edit the cookies.  Someone could edit the cookie to contain a different time, and therefore edit a blog post from years ago.

I'd hope you are using a Database to hold the blog posts, and if so, the time they were created is simply another column.  You could even have it auto populate with the current time when the blog was first created.

Are you creating this blog software just for fun, or for an actual business purpose?  If its for an actual business  you might want to look at some free popular blogging tools.

- http://wordpress.org/
- http://joomla.org